# Export .net dataset to XLS files

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

Is there a quick way to export .NET dataset to XLS file without using VBA or MS lib?
I want to append my XLS report file.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like FlexCel:

http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/flexcelnet.asp

Perhaps I should also ask what you would like to see as the output because there are a lot of other options. You could use a CSV file if you just want the data displayed in columns, there are number of report writers that will export to XLS files and a number of Grids that will export to XLS files. If you are happy with XLSX then you could create the file you want in the correct format of XML which is what XLSX uses to store data internally.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have xls file report with img and report title and I want to append that file with data in columns.

Comment: About the only thing you can use to do that is something like FlexCel which I linked to above. Thats because you are modifying an XLS file. So you will need to open the XLS file and then iterate through the dataset and set the columns. A much better approach would be to create the .xls from scratch using a reporting tool like DevExpress XtraReports (http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/) in which you create a report which matches your XLS layout and then export the report to the XLS file.

Comment: You can also use RDLC reporting which is bundled with Visual Studio. Here is a site with some tutorials on it (http://gotreportviewer.com/). It's not as flexible as Visual Studio but the price is right :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Aspose.Cells for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) to add/import data into Worksheet? This component can help you [import data from dataset and other sources to an existing worksheet](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/importing-data-to-worksheets.html). You can also [import data into individual cells](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/adding-data-to-cells.html) as well. This component doesn't require MS Office to be installed on the development or deployment machines in order to work with Excel files. The API is easy to learn and implement and works on any Windows OS and 32-bit/64-bit systems seamlessly.

Disclosure: I work as a developer evangelist at Aspose.